# Странный эффект от перевода IE в режим отладки (F12)

Tags: internet-explorer, кроссбраузерность

Кто-нибудь встречал такой эффект: 
а) открываешь страницу в Эксплорере - ошибка (последний компонент - на всё окно);
б) жмешь F12 - отладка (ничего больше не делаешь!);
в) перегружаешь страницу - всё работает!
Причем, магическое действие оказывает само включение режима отладки - после его выключения и перезагрузки страница отображается правильно. Но если закрыть и открыть 
Эксплорер - эффект исчезает.
Если кто встречал и поборол, отпишите, пожалуйста. 
Прим. В FireFoxe всё было в норме.

Comment: Причин может быть сколько угодно. Например при ошибке с асинхронной загрузкой скриптов — в первый раз не успел загрузить, во второй раз взял из кэша и успел.

Comment: Что делать-то?

Comment: предоставить чуточку больше данных. Все телепаты разбрелись.

Comment: ВОПРОС снят: ошибку вызывала строчка 'console.log("xx")' в IE9 c отключенной по умолчанию отладкой сценариев. При вкл. режима отладки данная ошибка не возникала и всё загружалось нормально.